# Why does React setState need the spread of the existing state but not always?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In an exercice I updated a `grid: boolean[][]` in the state with:

```
    this.setState({ grid: newGrid });
```

My state is composed of the grid and another boolean.

```
type LightsOutGameState = {
  grid: boolean[][];
  isWinned: boolean;
};
```

No problem, working and no error.

But with a new exercise concerning the forms I try to make the `handleInput` with:

```
  handleInputChange(evt) {
    this.setState({
     [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value,
    });
   }
```

and I got an error.

> The argument of type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BoxState | ((prevState: Readonly, props:
> Readonly) => BoxState | Pick<BoxState, keyof BoxState> |
> null) | Pick<...> | null'.ts(2345)

I found out that if I use the spread operator to fill a copy of the existing state it work like this:

```
  handleInputChange(evt) {
    this.setState({
     ...this.state,
     [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value,
   });
 }
```

the state is :

```
type BoxState = {
  width: string;
  height: string;
  color: string;
};
```

Why do I need to fill the copy of the state in my second example but I do not in my first one? I thought this was because the `newGrid` (in the first example) was set using the old state so TypeScript knows, but if I initialize it with a fresh new array it's still okay. I precise that I tested to not use computed property.

Comment: What error did you get? And what was the exercise?

Comment: *"...and I got an error..."* ***What*** error? The second call to `setState` you've shown is arguably incorrect, because it may override a state change that's been queued but not yet processed because you may be setting based on stale state (although if you're doing this in response to end-user events that's a bit unlikely). So the former is more likely to be correct, hence the question: What error?

Comment: the error is L'argument de type '{ [x: number]: any; }' n'est pas attribuable au paramètre de type 'BoxState | ((prevState: Readonly<BoxState>, props: Readonly<BoxProps>) => BoxState | Pick<BoxState, keyof BoxState> | null) | Pick<...> | null'.ts(2345)
and the exercice is creating a form with width,height and color field that create a box when submitting.

Comment: Side note: `class` components are now [a legacy API](https://react.dev/reference/react/legacy). Consider learning function components with hooks instead.

Comment: @eephyne - Thanks. Please use the "edit" link and put the error message (translated into English) **in** the question. Please include the *whole* message (what you've shown is usually followed by more information saying *why* the types are incompatible).

Comment: @eephyne Please add the error in the question itself

Comment: That's a _type_ error, from the transpiler, and tells you nothing about what difference there might be at runtime. You haven't shown us the type of anything you're working with, give a [mre].

Comment: Separately: I find it hard to believe that error is produced by the code given. It says that `{ [x: number]: any; }` is not assignable to the state type, but the code you've shown will **not** be providing a number key in the object. The `name` property of an element (`target`, in your example) is always a string.

Comment: I added the state for both example, I can provide the full file if needed but i do not want to overflow the thread.

Comment: @eephyne - We don't need the whole file, but we do need a [mre]. Those are different things. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that TypeScript doesn't know that the object you're providing is a valid subset of the state type in your component, because `evt.target.name` and `evt.target.value` are both strings, but just "any string" isn't a valid property key for your state type (and even if it were, it might not be for a property whose type is `string`). Your workaround using `...this.state` tells TypeScript that the object is assignable to your state type.

**But**, your workaround may (in some cases) mean you're overwriting an in-progress state update, because you're re-setting all of your state properties.

Here are three solutions for you (in the realm of a `class` component):

1. Use an assertion function to check that the `name` you're using is a valid key for a string-typed property in your state type:

   ```
   // ...outside the component...
   type KeysOfType<ObjectType, PropertyType> = keyof {
       [Key in keyof ObjectType as ObjectType[Key] extends PropertyType ? Key : never]: ObjectType[Key];
   };

   function assertIsValidStringStateKey(name: string): asserts name is KeysOfType<ThingState, string> {
       // Your real implementation here would want to be more robust
       if (name !== "a") {
           throw new Error();
       }
   }

   // ...in the component...
   handleInputChange({ target: { name, value }}: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
       assertIsValidStringStateKey(name);
       this.setState({
           [name]: value,
       });
   }
   ```
2. Use your workaround, but using the callback form so that you don't potentially override in-progress state updates:

   ```
   this.setState((state) => ({
       ..state,
       [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value,
   }));
   ```
3. Bludgeon it with a type assertion. :-D I'm not a fan of doing this, but there are times...

   ```
   this.setState({
       [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value,
   } as unknown as BoxState);
   ```

I'd probably go with option #1 or #2.

Here's an example of all three ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVgQBYokDmSAogG7nwC+cAZlEXAERRUGfgG4AUOOAUkULuiRwAQhAAeAZRgoYinOLgG4KAFxwAzjCjS6Ew3ABGpkgFcQ92RPaSYATzCKAaSQfMwB5LgAVPyQAHlD7ACskDCj-bAAFXn9YH1SkAD44AF44AGtgiC5cfUMAbSCfOGkyiqr4pJToozM4duSYPPrggF04JFUdEgATHsyIbN88uAB+OAa4JyRWKGHTPs7-IZ9hzwlxLmcSDGBSbrNZGABJMwA1FAAbYCnNK3pNbSQDQAFCQUCAkKYLL86ABKUwoMz3WA9UHgpo9BphSLRGIqDRaHTYKHWQp6OwAenJcAAmhBnFA4EIPk1wO8kOCKNobiQ4FRZIoAO5095TOAC2jwGAQByKEDQRS8ezOCw1AzAKogsGKACERRK-BQ-Bh1TsdhgVF4ArgZCtjCgvCgQJhtkMXi84jQ7wRPTxYwm5BmBCIkDIFBiOHY2Dx-x0pNVcDQpChzgw0CBYCyZlMEeNZNNBjMzmy6czzvjZqowDMADoLADiib86aTAJ+Jhy03HHAAAztptwdgu-PmqvVmjTNmPEhgZwwfDjhgNkc18dTSfT2fz2gMav2aRTIHLst2d12VfrmdzhdIIF4LRQBgwbPWrXYZgfZyKdjsUxb+hMVgwwACQiABZAAZKdL0YNkORgfJcw7AxKTgAARdkk0sLl6Dgc1FGgYA6GkZkMwgexYLgABaSixntaBeX5JDcMrGt7hgGMbzzfsDFqVEkF2OB33eT8+ybdgyyYlCAGIAEYmO9B5njeT5vksawOOBPjjybZdayQdiCU4pi7F4rUBKEkSmPEs5+2kgAmJjdLYjigSBOsdGNIpClvYzDGrfz3KQUTuLgUzwXMj8gqsmEJNsqkpIAZkcli9IMgEfJCni+Ii4Sov7TgETgS5ShICABR5Qro0M7SDFPQwhGmWQnUbfMhBgekeRiaRLxfcEigNfhcOifqdAmQbSD-BgihwXTzyQKDN2vTgLKQaanMM6sUE4cl8iHAdxC8IA)):

```typescript
import React, { Component, ChangeEvent } from "react";

interface BoxState {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

type KeysOfType<ObjectType, PropertyType> = keyof {
    [Key in keyof ObjectType as ObjectType[Key] extends PropertyType ? Key : never]: ObjectType[Key];
};

function assertIsValidStringStateKey(name: string): asserts name is KeysOfType<BoxState, string> {
    // Your real implementation here would want to be more robust
    if (name !== "a") {
        throw new Error();
    }
}

class Box extends Component<{}, BoxState> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            a: "",
            b: 0,
        };
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange({ target: { name, value }}: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        // Demonstrating the original problem -- error here
        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });

        // #1
        assertIsValidStringStateKey(name);
        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });

        // #2
        this.setState((state) => ({
            ...state,
            [name]: value,
        }));

        // #3
        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        } as unknown as BoxState);
    }

    render() {
        return <input name="a" type="text" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.a} />;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so using ...this.state tell typescript "okay, you have all the data you require for this" but does that mean the line [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value could be anything and typescript accept it since it already have all the required value ? I thought using a type restrain the data to only those who are declared in this type (no more no less) ?

Comment: @eephyne - Smart question. Yes, in theory that property definition could add a property that doesn't exist on your state type. In general case, that's not a type violation, it just means that the object being provided is a *subtype* of the type that's expected. That's a common thing to do in OOP. For instance, consider the DOM's `appendChild`. It expects a `Node`, but it can accept *any* kind of `Node`, including the `Node` subtypes `Element`, `HTMLElement`, `HTMLInputElement`, etc. that have more properties than `Node` has. So in general, TypeScript allows you to use an object that's...

Comment: ...a subtype of the type of object it expects. In some cases, TypeScript can and will apply [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks) in places where it seems likely the excess properties are an error, but that's just a lint-style check; the excess properties aren't *wrong* from a type perspective. While it can usually apply those checks to an object literal used as a function arg, it's not doing it with `setState` here. I suspect that's b/c it can't if the function's type definition is sufficiently complex like `setState`'s.

Comment: ok, that make sense. just a last question on the way, I tried to do this instead `if (evt.target.name === 'color' ) { setState here with computed property }` but that don't work but if I do  `this.setState({ color: evt.target.value });` hard coded it work. I also thougt that  using conditonnal like this would work , but apparently not  in this case, do you know why ?

Comment: @eephyne - Because it's an object property, and TypeScript's flow analysis can't generally handle it in that case (even though it *could*; there are trade-offs in terms of compilation time). If you did `const { name } = evt.target; if (name === "color") { this.setState({[name]: evt.target.value}); }` that would work. That's basically solution #1 above, just inline instead of with an assertion function.